# how to execute 'flutter run' with an apk path?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-test

Is there a way to execute `flutter run` with an apk path instead of a target path like: `-t ./test_drive/main.dart`?

I have the instrumented apk in my hand and would like to run it in debug mode where I can get the Observatory debugger URL the same way I get it when running `flutter run -t ./test_driver/main.dart`:

```
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86 64. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching ./test_driver/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        12.4s
✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...                 3.8s
Waiting for Android SDK built for x86 64 to report its views...         10ms
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86 64...            217ms

Flutter run key commands.
r Hot reload. 
R Hot restart.
h Repeat this help message.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).
An Observatory debugger and profiler on Android SDK built for x86 64 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:55897/aOmlBKN310Y=/
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the option I need, it is called `--use-application-binary`, verbose mode needs to be enabled in order to see this option `flutter run -h -v`.